# Download first n lines/characters using RCurl

Tags: r, curl, callback, rcurl

I need to use the package RCurl to download the content of various URLs (using authentification, etc.).
To optimize download speed I would like to limit the downloaded response output lines / characters since I only need the first 20 lines of each page and the whole content size can be very big.

Using readLines this could be done quickly, e.g.:

```
readLines("http://www.nytimes.com/", n = 20L)
```

However using RCurl, and specifying the maximum character parameter I do not get the expected result:

```
test <- getURL("http://www.nytimes.com/", write = basicTextGatherer(max = 1000))
> nchar(test)
[1] 125709
```

According to the RCurl [FAQ page](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/faq.html#How_do_I_make_libcurl_not_receiv) a customized callback function should do the trick, however, I don't exactly know how.

Comment: With the `max` argument, the function stops once it has accumulated 1000 characters or more: in this case, it receives 125,000 characters in one block, and then stops, without reading the remaining 3,000 characters. I guess you would only see a difference on much larger files.

Comment: thanks for the info, have already rewritten my code to avoid this problem - but still interested if there are any "hard character limits" for RCurl.

Comment: @user625626, have you find out any solution?